# How do I start this vector field problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Consider the tetrahedron $ABCD$ where the vertices $A , B , C$ and $D$ have the Cartesian coordinates:

$$A=(0,0,0), \quad  B=(1,0,0), \quad  C=(0,2,0) \quad \text{and} \quad  D=(0,0,3)$$

Draw the tetrahedron

Confirm that the plane $BCD$ has the equation $6x+3y+2z=6$
making sure that $B,C$ and $D$ all satisfy the equation

Deduce that:

1. $BC$ has equation $y=2-2x$.
2. $DB$ has equation $z=3-3x$.
3. $CD$ has equation $z=3-1.5y$.

Question: How do I draw the tetrahendron and how do I confirm the equation given hence, therefore, leading to work out $BC,DB,CD$ ?

Comment: All the points are on the major axes, so the lines $BC, BD, CD$ are on the $xy,xz,yz$-planes.

Comment: For the plane you need the intercept form of the equation (BCD are 3 intercepts on X Y and Z axes). And to deduce the equation of line you can use the parametric form of the line.